# PHP update div after click submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to do update "refresh" `div` after click *Submit* button and also every 5 seconds. I checked some questions, but I could not find what I was looking for.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?php 
    echo '<div id="refresh">';
        while ($r = $q->fetch()):
            echo 'Sender: ';
            if($r['senderid'] == $a) {echo $query1['username'];}
            elseif($r['senderid'] == $b) {echo $query2['username'];}
            echo '</br>';
            echo $r['message'];
            echo '</br></br>';
        endwhile;
    echo '</div>';
    ?>

    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="a" value="<?php echo $a;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="b" value="<?php echo $b;?>">
        <textarea name="message" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission action
            $.post("submit.php", $("form").serialize()); // Post the data
            $('textarea[name=message]').val('')
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Unclear, What result do you have ?

Comment: You are missing  `$.post("submit.php", $("form").serialize(), function(data) { $("refresh").html(data)});`

Comment: @mplungjan I try your suggestion but not work :(

Comment: What result do you have now ?, I think, u want empty field after submit form, it is ?

Comment: I want update DIV (id=refresh) after i post form

Comment: I missed a #: `$("#refresh").html(data)`

Comment: @mplungjan yes thank you it works :) Last thing i need your help. I could not refresh div every 5 seconds

Comment: Use setTimeout from after the update statement

Comment: I try this but not works '$(document).ready(function() {
       setTimeout(#refresh,1000); 
    });'

Comment: You need to investigate how things work. setTimeout takes a function

Answer (score 0):

Please make some rudimentary investigation on [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Here is an example - there are a few questions you need to consider

```
var val = "";
function refreshDiv() {
   var $text = $('textarea[name=message]');
   val = $text.val() || val; // what to do if user clears the field?
   if (val == "") return; // stop if nothing there
   $.post("submit.php", $("form").serialize(),function(data) {
     $("#refresh").html(data)); // show the data
     setTimout(refreshDiv,5000); // call it again in 5 secs
     // $text.val(''); // not sure about this...
   });
}
$(function() {
    $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission action
      refreshDiv();
    });
});
```